# Rotation reverting on Mac display settings

Tags: macos, orientation, display, macos-catalina

I have four Dell monitors connected to Mac Pro. Rotation reverts to Standard for other displays if I change one to 90 degrees in System Preferences -> Displays. This used to work before the forced update. I'm on MacOs Catalina 10.15.7.

It's hard to work on this machine with monitors disoriented. What are my options to get back to the corrected orientations as before?

Answer (score 0):

In frustration, I rebooted my Mac Pro another time. And voila, the screen orientation is using the original correct ones so that all the vertical monitors are in alignment now.